# How to connect a Win XP PC and Win 7 PC with a Linksys WRT54G Router to a PPPOE connection?

Tags: router

I have two PCs and a WRT56G Router. My provider is a PPPOE connection (username and password). I can connect my Windows 7 easily. Even if I choose Auto or PPPOE on the router's configuration. Maybe because this one had the connection in the first place with the username and password set up.

But I can't connect the Windows XP PC. Actually it does connect in a way, but it receives and sents just a few packages. I can actually see in My Network Places how many packages does the Gateway make and it's a big difference. And it won't open any page.

How should I set up the router so I can give enough bandwith to the Windows XP PC ?

I've seen another problem that I forgot to mention. The router can't connect with the pppoe settings. I don't know why, but with Auto DHCP setting and my Windows 7 connected with pppoe settings works.

EDIT2:

I've installed Windows 7 on the other PC so I won't have any problem of compatibility betwen them. But I still can't connect the router with PPPOE settings to the internet. It looks like this:

[image]

If you need any other screens or info, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the PPPOE configuration within the router, and have both PCs using just a basic network config (dhcp through lan).

The PCs don't really care what kind of connection it is, and you only need the PPPOE setup on the PC side if you don't have a router.

**EDIT:**

Based on the info you added, the solution will be to get the router to connect with PPPOE.  Maybe do a pinhole reset (reset to factory default settings using the recessed button on the back) and set it back up again.